# What is best practice for save large form data in laravel with approx 20 fields and multiple image uploads and video upload

Tags: php, laravel, forms, upload

I am working on a project which is having a form for some product to save it includes approx 20+ field and also have multiple images upload (3 max.) and 1 video to be upload.

I am looking for the best practice i can go with that.
As submitting all data and files at once will take long time to submit the form.

Comment: Create a `transaction` and submit multiple forms.

Comment: @AndreiLupuleasa   Do you have any example for that ??

Comment: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/php-mysql-transaction/

Comment: There are plenty tutorials on web http://www.phpknowhow.com/mysql/transactions/

Answer (score 1):

In your case you should use [queue](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues).
1. You create a job, for example

```
php artisan make:job MediaUpload
```

2. Write your upload logic inside `handle()` function

```
public function handle(Request $request)
{
   // Process uploaded podcast...
}
```

3. Dispatch this job in your Controller

```
MediaUpload::dispatch($request);
```

P.S: Don't forget to configure your queue as shown in the link above.